# Mercurial: get active branches created by a given user

Tags: mercurial

We have quite many branches in our repository, I wonder if there is a quick way to list out all active branches created by myself.

Comment: Are these named branches?

Comment: yes, they are named branches

Answer (score 4):

You get all children of any branch point, whether named branch or unnamed branch by means of using revlogs:

`hg log -r"children(branchpoint())"`

Additionally you want to throw in `not closed()` and want to restrict it to yourself as user via `-u YOURNAME`.

Throw in a bit of bash and you get a list of active branches which you contributed to by

`hg log -u YOURNAME -r"children(branchpoint()) and not closed()" --template="{branch}: {rev}:{node|short}\n" | sort | uniq`

I rather use `--template="{branch}: {rev}:{node|short} {desc}\n"` in order to better see also the revisions and first commit message - but you can just limit it to `{branch}\n'.

Also see hg help revset for (further) help on advanced log searches - it allows very well refined searches. You might do without bash's sort and unique by using them even more extensively.

EDIT: changed quotes from single to double

Comment: unfortunately I got some error when running  " hg log -r'children(branchpoint())' " . It gives error unknow revision.

Comment: Try using double quotes rather than single quotes and make sure you've got a space between -r and the quote, e.g. `hg log -r "children(branchpoint())"

Comment: It works verbatim on my system, but maybe a different shell or OS might want other quotes, thus try double instead of single ones.

Comment: Windows command line gives the error without the double quotes.